coordinate of Geospatial with node js express and mangodb
i am using nodejs express and mangodb, when a user signup i want to get the live location of the use geospatial code . this is the error i get when i run my code .
MongoServerError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('675af307f2a7bcc8878ea08b'), citizenName: "citizen44", citizenEmail: "citizen44@email.com", hashedPwd: "$2b$10$wvGKMqASwi/cQryjRbGSluHJlbnrnZX6YKmxu2CoiqcSRBAsVILD2", location: ObjectId('675af307f2a7bcc8878ea088'), status: "student", role: { Basic: 1997 }, createdAt: new Date(1734013703839), updatedAt: new Date(1734013703839), __v: 0 }  geo element must be an array or object: location: ObjectId('675af307f2a7bcc8878ea088')

this the code // Register a new user
const registerNewUser  = async (req, res) => {
    // Validate request data
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).send({ errors: result.array() });
    }

    const data = matchedData(req);
    const { citizenName, citizenEmail, passCode, confirmPwd, latitude, longitude, status } = data;

    try {
        // Create location object
        const location = new Location({
            location: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
            }
        });

        // Save the location to the database
        const savedLocation = await location.save();

       
        // Check for duplicate citizen name
        const duplicate = await Citizen.findOne({ citizenName: citizenName }).exec();
        if (duplicate) {
            return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Citizen name already exists' });
        }

       

        // Hash the password
        const hashedPwd = await bcrypt.hash(passCode, 10);

        // Create citizen document
        const citizen = new Citizen({
            citizenName,
            citizenEmail,
            hashedPwd,
            location: savedLocation._id, // Ensure this matches the schema
            status,
            role
        });

        // Save the citizen to the database
        await citizen.save();

        return res.status(201).send(citizen);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Content was not uploaded', error: err.message });
    }
};

this is the model of the location
// models/location.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // name: { type: String, required: true },
    location: {
        type: { type: String, enum: ['Point'], required: true },
        coordinates: { type: [Number], required: true } // [longitude, latitude]
    }
});

// Create a geospatial index
locationSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });

const Location = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);

module.exports = Location;

i want to get the user live location and able to save it to the database get the last insertedID and insert it inside the citizen collection.
